Google Search Title and Icon different than that of in the browser tab for React Project
When I search for my website on Google, I see a different icon and title than the one I specificed in my code and then one I see in my browser tab once the site is reached. The browser tab icon and title are working but the Google Search Icon and Title are just the default react icon and domain. (Used create-react-app and netlify deployment).
I tried adding every possible favicon and making sure I had the  tag in my index.html. While the browser tab reflected the intended changes, the google search did not. It's been about 2 weeks and nothing has changed after repeated index requests.
Here my relevant index.html meta tags:
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/favicon.ico"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/favicon-16x16.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="48x48"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/favicon-48x48.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="192x192"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/android-chrome-192x192.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="512x512"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/android-chrome-512x512.png"
    />

Google Search result
Browser Tab result

It sounds like you used React to build your site. How is your React website created? Did you use some framework like next.js, did you use create-react-app, or something different? That would help to answer your question.
I know that at least next.js uses some really subtle automatism for its favicons, and sometimes even actively removes manually added  entries. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons for more information, if you used next.js.

I used just a plain create-react-app with the src directory. I deployed my site using netlify.

Google looks for and updates your favicon whenever it crawls your page. Make sure you follow this Guidelines.
If you make changes to your favicon and want to inform Google about the changes, you can request indexing of your page. Updates can take a few days or longer to appear in search results.
